# Unhealthy Ingress services

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes-ingress, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy an application via GKE. As far I created two services and two deployments for the front and the back for the App .
I created an ingress ressource using "gce" controller and I mapped the services as shown

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app
    part: ingress
  name: my-irool-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-ip
spec:
 backend:
    serviceName: client-svc
    servicePort: 3000
 rules:
  - http:
        paths:
        - path: /back
          backend:
            serviceName: back-svc
            servicePort: 9000
  - http:
        paths:
        - path: /back/*
          backend:
            serviceName: back-svc
            servicePort: 9000
```

It worked almost fine ( not all the root where mapped correctly but it worked). I added modification on the code ( only the code of the application ) and I rebuild the images and recreated the services, but the ingress seemed angry with the modifications I have added and

> all my services became in the unhealthy state

This is the front service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app
    part: front
  name: client
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - nodePort: 32585
    port: 3000
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
     app: app
     part: front
```

when I do a describe , I got nothing beside that my services are unhealthy.
And in the moment of creation I keep getting

> Warning  GCE      6m                loadbalancer-controller 
>   googleapi: Error 409: The resource
>   '[project/idproject]/global/healthChecks/k8s-be-32585--17c7......01'
>   already exists, alreadyExists

My question is:

- What is wrong about the code showed above? Should I map all the services to the port 80 ( default ingress port so it could work? )
- What are the readinessProbe and livenessProbe? Should I add them or mapping one to the services to default backend should be enough ?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, [deleting and re-creating the ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/330) may resolve the issue. For the second question, you can review the full steps of configuring Liveness and Readiness probes [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/). Furthermore, as defined [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes) (as an example for a pod):

> livenessProbe: Indicates whether the Container is running. If the
>   liveness probe fails, the kubelet kills the Container, and the
>   Container is subjected to its restart policy. If a Container does not
>   provide a liveness probe, the default state is Success.
>
> And readinessProbe: Indicates whether the Container is ready to
>   service requests. If the readiness probe fails, the endpoints
>   controller removes the Pod’s IP address from the endpoints of all
>   Services that match the Pod. The default state of readiness before the
>   initial delay is Failure. If a Container does not provide a readiness
>   probe, the default state is Success.